# Is there or will there be a Scala collection extending Seq with faster iteration than Array?

Tags: scala, performance, collections

From what I tested and [read](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html), `Array` is the fastest collection when it comes to do random access or iteration through `foreach`, `while`, and `tailrec`, but they are mutable, unlike `Vector`, which is unfortunately not as fast as `Array`.

I'm still stuck on Scala 2.11, but I recently discovered that changes have been made on Scala 2.13. Is there some hope that there exists or will exist an immutable collection that surpasses `Array` in term of random access?

Here is an exemple for euclidean distance on `Array[Double]`, it works exactly the same on Seq descendants.

```
    final def euclidean(v1: Array[Double], v2: Array[Double]): Double = {
      @annotation.tailrec
      def go(d: Double, i: Int): Double = {
        if(i < v1.size) { 
          val toPow2 = v1(i) - v2(i)
          go(d + toPow2 * toPow2, i + 1)
        }
        else d
      }
      sqrt(go(0D, 0))
    }
```

Comment: `2.13` will have an [immutable **Array**](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq.scala).

Comment: I just tried comparing euclidean distance using `tailrec` and ArraySeq are still ~10% slower for 1M runs.

Comment: What do you mean with `tailrec`? A tail-recursive algorithm that splits the collection using `head` & `tail`? If so, you probably better use a **List** instead of an **Array**. Every `tail` call will copy the contents of the array to a new one. **Arrays** are good for iterative algorithms.

Comment: I'm not using tail and head in this case, just replace the while loop by a tail recursive call to iterate over `X <: Seq` or `Array`.

Comment: Can you pleae share the code in the question. I am not an expert about collections, but if you look at the source, the _immutable_ **Array** is just a wrapper over a normal _(mutable)_ **Array**. So, they should behave very similar, or at least I believe so.

Comment: Code example added

Comment: Uhm... it is pretty weird that it could be 10% slower using an **ArraySeq** since you only call `size` _(which is the same as `length`)_ and `apply`, a both of these methods forward to the underlying mutable `Array`. Being a wrapper there is a bit of overhead... but 10% is insane big and the **JIT** should be able to inline the forward calls after a few runs. Maybe you should open an issue, or report that in the gitter channel. Hopefully someone with better understanding than me could help you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think it is possible to surpass `Array` in terms of random access in JVM. As the array element are of equal size and they are located sequentially in memory, the position of an element can be quickly calculated in constant time using the given index. What is more, this leads to good cache locality.

In the best case the collection can have random access performance on par with arrays. Taking a look of scala 2.11 sources for the mentioned `ArraySeq`, it says:

> This means that elements of
>    *  primitive types are boxed.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq.scala#L19

This most likely explains the observed 10% drop in performance. Arrays have method `toSeq` which is implemented as a `WrappedArray` and there is specialized implementation for each primitive types which I believe is the most performant collection in scala 2.11 to wrap an array https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.scala#L173 .